# ZSH: splitting a string at quotation marks

Tags: split, zsh, substitution

Is there a way to split a string at quotation marks?

I tried this code, but it doesn't split the string at the quotation mark.

```bash
STRING='imgdir="/path/to/my/images"'
VAR=${$(s/\"/)STRING}
```

I have a file that contains data in the following format. I'd like to easily access the values in quotation marks.

```bash
imgdir="/path/to/my/images"
imgdir2="/path/to/my/images2"
testvalue="554"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file only contains assignments as shown (and no non-shell syntax), just source it:

```
. /path/to/file
```

Then you have all string values in the shell variables `imgdir`, `imgdir2`, `testvalue`, ..., with the quotes removed.

**EDIT**: If there's non-shell syntax, grep for the assignments first:

```
grep -E '[a-z0-9_]+=".*"' > assignments
. ./assignments
rm assignments
```

Comment: Thanks - but unfortunately there is a lot of other "stuff" in the file (which is not commented out) - I should probably have mentioned this :)

Comment: @Gerhard Added a way to deal with non-shell syntax.

Answer (score 0):

okay, answering my own question:

```
eval $(grep "imgdir=" $FILE)
```

does the trick for what I want to do in this case: It assigns a variable "imgdir" with what is between the quotation marks...

The original question remains though: how to split a string at quotation marks...

/Gerhard